# Do you have better dynamic way to shorten a complicate code jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know do I have a dynamic way to combine the following code into a short one. I have a lot of if().is(:checked){}else{}, can I do something like, if(this).is(:checked), I am trying to use .closest(), but don't know how to implement it, also thinking to use array? Do you any way? appreciate.

```js
 if ($("#diet_se").is(':checked')) {
      $('#diet_voting').fadeIn();
   $('#label_s2').addClass("label_se_active");
   
   jQuery("textarea[class*=expand1-99]").TextAreaExpander();//initialize the text expand
        }else{
      $('#diet_voting').fadeOut();
   $('#label_s2').removeClass("label_se_active");           
        }
        if ($("#exer_se").is(':checked')) {
      $('#exer_voting').fadeIn();
   $('#label_s3').addClass("label_se_active");
   
   jQuery("textarea[class*=expand1-99]").TextAreaExpander();//initialize the text expand
        }else{
      $('#exer_voting').fadeOut();
   $('#label_s3').removeClass("label_se_active");           
        }
        if ($("#reme_se").is(':checked')) {
      $('#reme_voting').fadeIn();
   $('#label_s4').addClass("label_se_active");
   
   jQuery("textarea[class*=expand1-99]").TextAreaExpander();//initialize the text expand
        }else{
      $('#reme_voting').fadeOut();
   $('#label_s4').removeClass("label_se_active");           
        }
        if ($("#medi_se").is(':checked')) {
      $('#medi_voting').fadeIn();
   $('#label_s5').addClass("label_se_active");
   
   jQuery("textarea[class*=expand1-99]").TextAreaExpander();//initialize the text expand
        }else{
      $('#medi_voting').fadeOut();
   $('#label_s5').removeClass("label_se_active");           
        }
        if ($("#others_se").is(':checked')) {
      $('#others_voting').fadeIn();
   $('#label_s6').addClass("label_se_active");
   
   jQuery("textarea[class*=expand1-99]").TextAreaExpander();//initialize the text expand
        }else{
      $('#others_voting').fadeOut();
   $('#label_s6').removeClass("label_se_active");           
        }
  } // function menu_check
```

Comment: Would help to see the html structure in order to help set up traverses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're correct in thinking that you can shorten this code. The structure of the if/else code is the same for each element, so you can write:

```
var elements = { "diet": "2", "exer": "3", "reme": "4", :"medi": "5", "others": "6" };
$(elements).each(function (label_name, element_name) {
    if ($("#" + element_name _ + "_se").is(':checked')) {
        $('#' + element_name _ + '_voting').fadeIn();
        $('#label_s' + label_name).addClass("label_se_active");

        jQuery("textarea[class*=expand1-99]").TextAreaExpander(); //initialize the text expand
    } else {
        $('#' + element_name _ + '_voting').fadeOut();
        $('#label_s' + label_name).removeClass("label_se_active");
    }
})
```

I haven't tested this code but aside from syntax errors I think it's correct.

Comment: thanks for your time. You code help me a lot thought there is a syntax errors. I change the line two to this jQuery.each( obj, function( i, val ) {